# Does a database connection close automatically on Redirect?

Tags: asp.net, database-connection

I'm doing a project in ASP.NET.

I wanted to know whether a connection would close automatically when jumping from one page to another in a web application.

Or will it show the error `MAX POOL SIZE WAS REACHED`?

Comment: It will not close automatically, you need to handle it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A database connection is a server-side thing, and has very little to do with "jumping from one page to another" - the server just sees requests.

Now: If you open a connection during a request, it *is* important that you get around to closing it too; otherwise, it will only be closed by the garbage collector. In many cases, closing a connection *actually* means "release the *underlying* connection to the pool".

So: if you are seeing "MAX POOL SIZE WAS REACHED", there is indeed a good chance that you have failed to close your connections. That doesn't really map  to "jumping from page to another", though. Just: requests that don't clean up after themselves properly.

The easiest way to ensure you do this is via the `using` statement, but it depends a bit on your scenario.